# In which section I can review the reason why I lost points?

Tags: support, answers, down-votes, statistics

I have recently seen a loss of points in my profile, I have reviewed all my post and it seems that I don't have negative points.

I can usually see this in **Activity** > **Reputation**

But neither shows a description of the reason and I have not received a notification, I'm interested to know since this way I can check if indeed I have erred in giving an answer.

Best Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I **wasn't** due to you giving bad answers.

Having looked at your profile, I see:

- **-140** points on May 4th
- **-30** points on April 10th

There was an issue with a certain user (won't mention any names) who was using multiple accounts to serial up vote his account, along with others users. This user had their account suspended for 30 days.

Don't worry though, it wasn't just you, I and other members also had point deducted.

Comment: Thank you _@Lodder_, extra to this, it's possible that the points also will reduce when we make revisions type _"Close Votes"_ or similar?

Comment: No, vote to close doesnt deduct any points. If you down vote a question/answer, you do however get 1 point deducted

Comment: @AlexVega: it's -1 point only when you downvote an answer. Donwvoting Questions doesn't deduct points.

Comment: Oops, my bad. :/

Answer (score 0):

If anyone else has the same doubt, extra to the above information, I found:

- In the section **Activity** > **Reputation** at the bottom of the list there is an option called
   **Show Removed Posts**.

  From here I have been able to audit some of the points that I lost.

And some useful links:

- https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation
- [How do I audit my reputation?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43004/how-do-i-audit-my-reputation)